# How to test behavior based on private class using members c++ using gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

I want to use Google test to test my class.
Lets assume I have a state machine implementation and the current state is private 
so I have a method SetNextState that looks  like that:

```
void setNextState
{
  switch(m_currentState) //m_currentState is a private member
  {
    case INIT_STATE:
    {
       if some conditions occurred m_currentState=GO_STATE
    } 
......
  }
}
```

so I have several cases and each define the behavior to move from certain state to another.
My question:
How do I perform tests on that method assuming the state is relevant only to this class so there is no output 
How do I set its value to be, for example "GO_STATE" to test the GO_STATE case 
and how do i check the m_currentState at the end of the test 
Im trying to avoid putting friends etc. in my UUT code since I want it to be as original as possible

Comment: i fixed the code formatting, would be cool if you could insert one or more . / ? somewhere in the last paragraph to make it readable ;)

Answer (score 5):

You don't. You do the same thing that your actual program will do, which is provide an input, then examine the result; you say there's no output, but there must be *some* effect, otherwise the class is pointless!

Failing that, you *could* make the test a "friend" of the class so that it can inspect its internals, or add an immutable getter for the current state (and who really cares if your class's users get to see that?) but neither option is really in the spirit of the thing.

In my experience, you'll occasionally realise that you're not really unit testing any more but instead *functional* testing, and Google Test may not be the right tool for that job. If your class is as big as it sounds, that could be the case here. Conversely, you could help yourself by splitting the class into smaller chunks, then unit testing *those*. Depends what you're going for, really.

Comment: Ill try to explain my concern :
Lets assume I have states 1 to 5 and I want to test behavior on state number 3
I agree that the output is not an issue since there is no point if there is no output to the outside world, but I have a mechanism that "publish" the output to listeners and I wanted to make the test simple. 
Regarding the input, In order to get to step 3 "legally" my test needs to provide all inputs to pass states 1,2 and again, I want to make the test simple and not check a process of my system ,  Only state 3 behavior. For that reason I wanted to "bend the rules"

Comment: @TalV. Sounds like my final paragraph is relevant to you then

Answer (score 4):

[Lightness Races in Orbit is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52296431/598696). However, if  sometimes you feel like it's useful to test the private member functions of your class, it often means that your class could be split in multiple smaller pieces.

If you don't think those smaller components are useful to the clients of your library, you can simply hide them in a `detail::` namespace and then create unit tests as usual. This will allow you to test the internal behavior of your classes without polluting your public API.

Answer (score 0):

After much considerations I decided to wrap my UUT with a helper which provides set and get to the relevant private members.and use it in the test procedure before calling the tested API

```
Original code
=============== 

class UUT //That's the actual class I want to test
{
  protected: 
     int m_protectedMember;
  public:
     void methodToTest()
     {
        //Do something with m_protectedMember use its value as input 
        //and set it as output 
     }
};

In the tester 
==============
class UUTHelper: public UUT
{
   public:
     int getProtectedMember() { return m_protectedMember; }
     void setProtectedMember(int value) { m_protectedMember = value; } 
};
```

The pros:

- My test code is very simple and I easily create complicated scenarios .
- I test the real code without any "friends" or any other manipulations.

The cons:

- As written in the discussion, not the best "good practice", touching private members

Thank you all :)